# How to prevent /usr/lib/tracker from using lots of CPU time?

Tags: gnome, performance, tracker

I have the problem that a `/usr/lib/tracker` process is using lots of CPU time in my Ubuntu installation.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nautilus file manager in gnome in kali linux in linked somehow to tracker process which is is /usr/lib/tracker , tracker eats lots of cpu , so i tried to

```
apt-get remove tracker
```

but seems somehow that tracker in linked to nautilus , so if you did this nautilus will not work and it you pressed on the places at the left corner of the screen it will not work , so

remove the following packages

```
apt-get remove tracker && apt-get remove nautilus && apt-get remove chirp
```

then install nemo , which is the default file manager for linux mint cinnamon

```
apt-get install nemo
```

this will solve the problem and tracker will not work anymore

do not try to change the permission of the files in /usr/lib/tracker

it will cause a problem in nautilus and will not work

and also removing tracker only will make nautilus not work

thank you for reading

UPDATE-->

sometimes the disk manager tool may appear instead if nemo when you press the places menu in the upper left corner , just remove the disk manager app , to get the name of disk manager app , go to show applications (the last button in the sandbox on the left of the desktop) , and search for disk manager ... open it .. go to help .. you will find the name of the tool , it starts with b..something , and do `apt-get remove 'the app name`